# ZFS on Linux + KVM Steals Memory

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, zfs

I'm having an issue with a CentOS 7 server where I have a single ZFS pool created along with (currently) a single running KVM VM (CentOS 6 guest). Top is reporting that the VM is using about 50% of my system's memory (which is correct - I have it configured for 16 GB out of 32 GB total), however, free reports my active memory in use as being around 26 GB. There is an extra 10 GB of RAM in use somewhere that I simply cannot find even though I have restricted ZFS to only use 4 GB for ARC. Top shows nothing else using memory:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
10928 qemu      20   0 20.773g 0.015t    680 S  55.8 50.7  12148:34 qemu-kvm
  530 root      20   0   59376   7940   7796 S   0.0  0.0   1:52.59 systemd-journal
 1913 root      20   0 1063816   5820   3120 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.36 libvirtd
 9005 root      20   0  135612   5344   4092 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.69 sshd
 8637 root      20   0  135612   5336   4092 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.42 sshd
    1 root      20   0   50960   4360   2152 S   0.0  0.0   0:12.09 systemd
11597 postfix   20   0   91636   3892   2892 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 pickup
 1400 root      20   0  378052   3168   2076 S   0.0  0.0   0:04.18 NetworkManager
 8651 root      20   0  115452   2140   1672 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.13 bash
 9020 root      20   0  115352   2056   1632 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bash
```

Free has no good info on where the RAM is (no, it's not filesystem cache, it is reported as actively in use):

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         31974      26534       5439         13          0         90
-/+ buffers/cache:      26444       5530
Swap:         1999        925       1074
```

My ZFS stats are reporting the ARC is within normal limits:

```
5 1 0x01 85 4080 3000154942 1126206978029170
name                            type data
hits                            4    626600066
misses                          4    531647209
demand_data_hits                4    324930179
demand_data_misses              4    239380938
demand_metadata_hits            4    246080774
demand_metadata_misses          4    33168747
prefetch_data_hits              4    55239743
prefetch_data_misses            4    256749089
prefetch_metadata_hits          4    349370
prefetch_metadata_misses        4    2348435
mru_hits                        4    170996240
mru_ghost_hits                  4    146648139
mfu_hits                        4    412479249
mfu_ghost_hits                  4    55201631
deleted                         4    522830695
recycle_miss                    4    688200803
mutex_miss                      4    5494038
evict_skip                      4    263172839174
evict_l2_cached                 4    2293824808448
evict_l2_eligible               4    3235679258112
evict_l2_ineligible             4    711594439680
hash_elements                   4    1003039
hash_elements_max               4    31494585
hash_collisions                 4    453192154
hash_chains                     4    298915
hash_chain_max                  4    105
p                               4    1899257344
c                               4    4294967296
c_min                           4    4194304
c_max                           4    4294967296
size                            4    4294703744
hdr_size                        4    428382448
data_size                       4    3463036928
meta_size                       4    268575232
other_size                      4    101467000
anon_size                       4    2181120
anon_evict_data                 4    0
anon_evict_metadata             4    0
mru_size                        4    1823588352
mru_evict_data                  4    1620893696
mru_evict_metadata              4    92227584
mru_ghost_size                  4    2367817728
mru_ghost_evict_data            4    1721548800
mru_ghost_evict_metadata        4    646268928
mfu_size                        4    1905842688
mfu_evict_data                  4    1840373760
mfu_evict_metadata              4    17820160
mfu_ghost_size                  4    1927131648
mfu_ghost_evict_data            4    1881784320
mfu_ghost_evict_metadata        4    45347328
l2_hits                         4    124320745
l2_misses                       4    404820103
l2_feeds                        4    1128427
l2_rw_clash                     4    52038
l2_read_bytes                   4    474159669248
l2_write_bytes                  4    246928839168
l2_writes_sent                  4    541747
l2_writes_done                  4    541747
l2_writes_error                 4    0
l2_writes_hdr_miss              4    6389
l2_evict_lock_retry             4    1037
l2_evict_reading                4    3
l2_free_on_write                4    3709466
l2_abort_lowmem                 4    1752
l2_cksum_bad                    4    0
l2_io_error                     4    0
l2_size                         4    2306560512
l2_asize                        4    2249048064
l2_hdr_size                     4    33242136
l2_compress_successes           4    45560845
l2_compress_zeros               4    0
l2_compress_failures            4    7074167
memory_throttle_count           4    0
duplicate_buffers               4    0
duplicate_buffers_size          4    0
duplicate_reads                 4    0
memory_direct_count             4    140693
memory_indirect_count           4    222279
arc_no_grow                     4    0
arc_tempreserve                 4    0
arc_loaned_bytes                4    0
arc_prune                       4    36031794
arc_meta_used                   4    831666816
arc_meta_limit                  4    3221225472
arc_meta_max                    4    10590063600
```

Here is the current ZFS configuration:

```
  pool: pool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 1h33m with 0 errors on Sat Dec  6 02:33:48 2014
config:

        NAME                                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        pool                                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            sda                                               ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb                                               ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-1                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc                                               ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd                                               ONLINE       0     0     0
        logs
          mirror-2                                            ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-INTEL_SSDSA2CW120G3_BTPR13600113120LGN-part3  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-INTEL_SSDSA2CW120G3_BTPR152503LQ120LGN-part3  ONLINE       0     0     0
        cache
          ata-INTEL_SSDSA2CW120G3_BTPR13600113120LGN-part4    ONLINE       0     0     0
          ata-INTEL_SSDSA2CW120G3_BTPR152503LQ120LGN-part4    ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

It seems I have 6+ GB of memory that have just *vanished* from the system, and I'm not sure what's going on here. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is _exactly_ the issue I ran into when evaluating ZFS on Linux, and why I currently don't use it.

Comment: I'm also currently using ZFS at home purely for file storage and so I don't really care that it's chewing up all the memory. On this box, however, I'm actually utilizing the box and it just puzzles me that it is doing this.

Comment: Please show your `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf`

Comment: Also `zfs get all pool` and `zpool get all pool` and your ZFS version.

Comment: @ewwhite /etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf:
options zfs zfs_arc_max=4294967296


Here's the zfs get all pool: http://imgur.com/lk9EVId

And zpool get all pool: http://imgur.com/5Uylnsn

Comment: @Ghan How big is your L2ARC?

Comment: @ewwhite The L2ARC is quite large: 2 x 86 GB SSD partitions striped together. Would managing those require extra RAM? And if so, why would it not still abide by the limitation?

Comment: @Ghan Because you're trying to do too much on too few resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of L2ARC... more than you should. This is not all magical... There are some ZFS best practices that should be part of the design.

L2ARC needs to be mapped in real
RAM. The best practice that I recall is ~1GB of RAM per 5GB of L2ARC. So you have 172GB of L2ARC... The system would need to be sized to ~34.5GB of RAM for ZFS. Taking a large chunk of that for a VM obviously impacts this.

Try using this system without L2ARC or using a much smaller amount of it.

In my environments, I optimize RAM wayyyy before adding an L2ARC device. Some say you shouldn't even go down that path until you have 64GB of RAM or more. If you have spare SSDs and want to use them, make a pool of SSDs.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know.  Do you know if there is a way to free up the used memory without rebooting after shrinking the partitions on the L2ARC?

Comment: `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`